# Controlling page breaks

Tags: export, notebooks

I'm writing a bunch of cells to a new notebook nb and am trying to control the pagebreaks. That is, I want a pagebreak after each `Length[listOef]` number of cells. But sometimes, I get two pagebreaks, depending on which random permutatation of `listOef`.

```
listOef
```

contains `"aantalVragen"` number of cells given by the user.

Then I use the following code:

```
nb = CreateDocument[Null, Magnification -> 1.5, ShowCellTags -> False, 
                          PageHeaders -> {{None, None, None}, {None, None, None}},
                          ShowCellLabel -> True];

(*Initialize exported notebook*)
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
NotebookDelete[nb];

allPermutations = Table[RandomPermutation[aantalVragen], {aantalToetsen}];

Do[
 NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Toets 1." <> ToString[toetsNummer], "Title", 
                        PageBreakAbove -> True]];
 NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[datumToets, "Text"]];
 NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Wiskunde", "Text", TextAlignment -> Right]];
 NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["G. Hollander", "Text", TextAlignment -> Right]];

 (* Test toetsNummer *)
   Do[
    NotebookWrite[nb, Permute[listOef, allPermutations[[toetsNummer]]][[vraagNummer]]];
    SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], 
               CellLabel -> "Vraag " <> ToString[vraagNummer] <> "."];
    SelectionMove[nb, After, Notebook])
    ,
    {vraagNummer, aantalVragen}];

 **SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
 SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], PageBreakBelow -> False];
 SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];**
 ,
 {toetsNummer, aantalToetsen}]

Export[exportAddress, nb];
```

Why does I sometimes get two pagebreaks? I then check if the last cell of the page has a pagebreak with the code

```
SelectionMove[nb,Previous,Cell];
Options[NotebookSelection[nb]]
```

at the end of every inner `Do[]` (which is for every page), but I get an empy list of options, so I don't know if there is a pagebreak or not.

Also, I'm not quite sure of the part of the code in ** Bold **: I'm trying to suppress pagebreaks at the end of a page, as I'm doing that with

```
 NotebookWrite[nb, 
  Cell["Toets 1." <> ToString[toetsNummer], "Title", PageBreakAbove -> True]];
```

at the beginning of the code. But that doesn't seem to prevent double page breaks, sometimes.

Any help/advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you get two pagebreaks? What inputs give you two pagebreaks? The **...** section doesn't seem necessary either.

Comment: I don't know which inputs give me two pagebreaks, that's the issue. Which ... section do you say isn't necessary?
Thanks!

Comment: I got caught by the 5 min comment edit limit. The section you seemed unsure about is not necessary. The program seemed to work fine on my computer, though I had to make assumptions about datumToets and other undefined symbols. Could you edit your code so we don't have to make so many assumptions?

Comment: Sure! Can I start a new discussion, or should I make an answer, as to get the correct formatting of the code?